# Video playback cuts off the last few seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm playing a video in unity, and short clips are fine, but longer ones cut off the last few seconds.  My video is 52 seconds and stops when about 50 have played.  I tried a random 2:45 video from the net, and it stopped after 2:41.  I can't figure out what's happening.

I tried video clip and URL.  Both have the issue.

```c#
IEnumerator playVideo(SubjectClipState clipState)
{
    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.Stop();
    clipState.clipObject.audioSource.Stop();

    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
    clipState.clipObject.audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = clipState.clipConfig.hasAudio ? VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource : VideoAudioOutputMode.None;
    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.controlledAudioTrackCount = clipState.clipConfig.hasAudio ? Convert.ToUInt16(1) : Convert.ToUInt16(0);
    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, clipState.clipConfig.hasAudio);
    if (clipState.clipConfig.hasAudio) clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, clipState.clipObject.audioSource);
    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.url = clipState.clipConfig.url;
    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.isLooping = clipState.clipConfig.endAction.type == "loop";
    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.Prepare();

    while (!clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.isPrepared)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    clipState.clipObject.videoPlayer.Play();
}
```

Note: the videoPlayer and audioSource are set elsewhere in the code.  LoopPointReached is attached.

I am playing it like this:

```c#
StartCoroutine("playVideo", subjectClipState);
```

LoopPointReached will break a couple seconds before it should be done.  The video player x/x frames is correct.   e.g. 2740/2740 frames.

Comment: Is this in the editor? A specific platform? All platforms?

Comment: I'm currently in the editor, yes. Windows 10.  Do you think it would not cut off should I try a rift build?

Answer (score 0):

ok, it turns out it was a bug with Unity 2018.2.  When I upgraded to 2018.3, it didnt cut off.